# Can I write an insert query using data from two joined tables?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, insert

I have a `SELECT` query like this:

```
SELECT id_default_value, id_type FROM ntg_attribute, ntg_module_attribute 
WHERE ntg_attribute.id_module_attribute = ntg_module_attribute.id;
```

This returns 2 columns, `id_default_value` and `id_type`. I'd like to then use this data as the basis of an `INSERT` query into another table, `ntg_default_value`, using `id_default_value` as the key, and `id_type` as the inserted value.

The following is nearly there, but not quite:

```
INSERT INTO ntg_default_value (id, id_type) 
SELECT id_default_value, id_type FROM ntg_attribute, ntg_module_attribute 
WHERE ntg_attribute.id_module_attribute = ntg_module_attribute.id;
```

This gives me:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "pk_ntg_default_value"
```

Is what I'm trying to do actually possible? If so, how do I construct the query?

(PostgreSQL 8.4.6)

Comment: Its possible. The error says the primary key already exists and the new row has a duplicate key. You need to construct a proper condition that will only select "new" rows that will not duplicate your PK. A common idiom is `insert into foo (...) select ... from bar ... where not exists (select 1 from foo where bar.id = foo.pk)` - will exclude rows where PK is already there.

Comment: Why are you duplicating data into another table?

Comment: @blthiewes I'm not duplicating the data, I'm migrating it. After the INSERT, I'm going to delete id_type from ntg_attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the constraint 'pk_ntg_default_value' probably means you are violating the primary key constraint of the table ntg_default_value.

Depending on your requirements you can either take away the primary key constraint. Or you can expand it to include both id & id_type if it doesn't already and add a GROUP BY to your query, if necessary, to prevent duplicate id_devault_value & id_type pairs. Your query becomes then :

```
INSERT INTO ntg_default_value (id, id_type)
SELECT id_default_value, id_type 
FROM ntg_attribute, ntg_module_attribute 
WHERE ntg_attribute.id_module_attribute = 
      ntg_module_attribute.id 
GROUP BY id_default_value, id_type
```